# ¿Cómo puedo obtener campos de un arreglo en un arreglo en un arreglo?

Tags: php, array

agradezco mucho el que me ayuden tan solo al ver mi problema, estoy tratando de mostrar información de clientes en un sitio web, descargo la información del servidor y lo paso de json a un array aqui el array:

```
    Array
(
    [Cte] => Array
        (
            [Login] => Array
                (

                    [ClaCte] => 999
                    [NomCte] => FARM                                                                                                                       
                    [ClaUN] => 14   
                    [ClaEmp] => 1

                )

            [SV] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [ClaCte] => 999
                            [FolioDocCte] => M-070978       
                            [DiasVen] => -1
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [ClaCte] => 999
                            [FolioDocCte] => M-071157       
                            [DiasVen] => -10
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [ClaCte] => 999
                            [FolioDocCte] => M-071166       
                            [DiasVen] => -10
                        )


                )

            [Dir] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [ClaCte] => 999
                            [ClaConsi] => 1
                            [NomConsi] => far.                                                                     
                            [DirEntrega] => 31 #109 
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [ClaCte] => 999
                            [ClaConsi] => 2
                            [NomConsi] => far.                                                                     
                            [DirEntrega] => 23 #612  
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [ClaCte] => 999
                            [ClaConsi] => 3
                            [NomConsi] => far.                                                                     
                            [DirEntrega] => 74 #244 
                        )                )

        )

)
```

Obviamente los resultados son mas grandes pero para fines prácticos estoy usando este fragmento, estoy tratando de obtener la información para mostrarla como un expediente del cliente, pero tengo problemas para llegar a la parte de DiasVen y DirEntrega
He tratado de realizar un foreach para llegar a esas partes pero me manda errores o warnings, aqui parte del codigo que uso:

```
include("usuario.php");
$array=revisarUsr($_POST['ClaUsuario'],$_POST['Contrasenia']);
if(!array_filter($array))
            {
                $msg="Error en los datos, intente de nuevo";
                header("Refresh: 5; URL=inicio.php");
                session_destroy();
                goto salida1;
            }
            else{
              $_SESSION['folio']=$_POST['ClaUsuario'];
              $_SESSION['trans']=$_POST['Contrasenia'];
              $msg="Datos verificados, espere un momento";
                $opcpassw=$array['Cte']['Login']['ClaEmp'];
                if ($opcpassw==1)
                {
                  
        foreach($array['Cte']['SV'] as $dias=>$valor)
        {
        print("<pre>".print_r($valor['DiasVen'],true)."</pre>");    
        }
                }
        }
```

Me gustaría, no la respuesta, sino donde leer especificamente y poder aprender, estoy 200% seguro que mi error esta en el foreach, lamentablemente no entiendo bien como manejarlo en la parte despues del "as" he tratado de leer la documentacion de PHP pero estoy batallando mucho.
Use el print_r solo para ver si estaba llegando correctamente al valor que busco, la manera como mostrare los datos será mas estetico en html, al final debo de mostrarle capa campo en su expediente.

Agradezco su tiempo y su apoyo ... muchas gracias.

Comment: La linea del print_r que errores o warnings te muestra?

Comment: Tu `foreach` está bien. He reproducido tu escenario (quitándole todo lo anterior al `foreach`) y me devuelve `<pre>-1</pre><pre>-10</pre><pre>-10</pre>`.  Como decía @Pipe... ¿cual es tu error o que crees que haces mal?

Comment: Hijole tienes razón, ya vi el error en mi código, era una maldita mayuscula, raiios, muchas gracias, pareciera que no, pero fueron de mucha ayuda al ver mi código, ahora lo que haré es tratar de identificar si en el arreglo aparece o no el campo de SV para que indique que tiene su historial limpio. Muchas gracias @masterguru

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En tu segundo bloque de código te falta una llave de cierre del else, no sé si lo tienes en tu archivo y aquí no lo copiaste.

Si esa es la solución, creo que tienes un problema de identación: fíjate el estandar PSR12 de PHP FIG https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/

Comment: Perdon, no se lo puse pero en mi archivo original si esta, una disculpa ahorita lo edito